# Message-level security with JAX-WS on WebSphereApplication Server V7

Tags: jax-ws, websphere-7

I'm new to web services. I was reading the following document on Message-level security with JAX-WS on WebSphere WebSphereApplication Server V7, Part 1: Using RationalApplication Developer V7.5.2 to build secure JAX-WSWeb services.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/tutorials/0905_griffith/

As per the document mentioned in the above link, The sample client is a stand-alone application. Under section Section 7. Testing secure JAX-WS,
they are setting the VM arguments through Run Configuration.

Here is my question. If my client is a web application which uses servlet/MVC framework like struts, then how do I pass the VM arguments for the authentication? is there a workaround for this?

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are asking about wsjaas_client.conf property. This is required when you run Java client not web client. If your client is web application you will just create for it bindings similarly, but configure differently UNT generator. You can provide user and password configuration or for example LTPA token.
Check here for more details [Configuring the username and password for WS-Security Username or LTPA token authentication](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_configusernamepwauth.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-15-5-1-5&lang=en)